# Trying to avoid a switch

Tags: c, switch-statement, mex

I'm using a function (`mxGetData()`) that returns a pointer `void*`, and depending on the variable `i_type` I need to treat the returned array as an array of integers, floats, doubles, etc. Right now I have a big switch to deal with each type, but is there any way of avoiding the switch? Notice that the pointers `uchr_dt`, `int_dt`, `flt_dt`, etc. are of different types.

```
switch(i_type){
case mxUINT8_CLASS:
  uchr_dt = (unsigned char*)mxGetData(var);
  break;
case mxINT32_CLASS:
  int_dt = (int*)mxGetData(var);
  break;
case mxUINT32_CLASS:
  uint_dt = (unsigned int*)mxGetData(var);
  break;
case mxSINGLE_CLASS:
  flt_dt = (float*)mxGetData(var);
  break;
case mxDOUBLE_CLASS:
  dbl_dt = (double*)mxGetData(var);
  break;
default:
  Fatal_Error("Input type not supported.\n");
}
```

--- UPDATE ---

After this I just need to iterate over the returned array.
I liked the idea of having a single `void *p` to avoid the switch above, but can how can I make sure that when I iterate over `p`, the pointer moves by the right amount? If the compiler sees `p` as a `double*`, but it is in fact a 'char*' (for example), it will get out of range.

```
double myCopy[nData];
for(i=0; i<nData; i++)
  myCopy[i] = (double) p[i];
```

Comment: There's always `if (i_type == mxUINT8_CLASS) { ... } else if (...)`.

Comment: You don't need to cast a void* (hello lundin) which may make a more "generic" solution possible . You could also just assign *all* pointers (provided you don't need their old values). For a handful of assignments that may still be faster than the conditional jump a switch amounts to. If i_type is an enum with small values you could hold an array of addresses of void pointers (all the `*_dt`, cast to `void*`) which is indexed by the type enum and just assign to the proper one. Or hold an array of function pointers to one-liners which do the assigning.

Comment: Do you need to have two of these arrays accessible at the same time? If not, may as well keep the live one in a generic form and only specialize it as-and-when (i.e. within the block where it's used).

Comment: You can cast the return value to a single `char*` and then advance the `char*` by the appropriate size at each iteration depending on the type.  Whatever tells you i_type could also tell you the size of the underlying type.

Comment: How are the `mx*_CLASS` defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using a union?

```
union {
  void* void_dr;
  unsigned char* uchr_dt;
  int* int_dt;
  // ...
} u;

u.void_dt = mxGetData(var);
```

Depending on the type, you'd then access `u.uchr_dt` etc.

Comment: Way better than mine!

Comment: It looks compact, but does not provide a check that the type is supported.

Comment: @AlexD Without seeing the full enum or rest of the code that actually processes the data, it's hard to tell how one would do this best...

Comment: Looks like you'd still need a switch and/or a C-style cast to actually use the pointer though.  I'm not sure if this solves any problem.  Might as well just use a void pointer, plus the aliasing in AlexD's answer.

Comment: @chappjc Well, the OP's current code requires at least two switch statements (of which they showed 1). This code requires at least one (of which it shows 0).

Comment: @immibis So I guess my problem is with the question then, but I'm still not clear why you wouldn't just go with a void pointer and cast it in the not-shown switch.

Comment: @StefanHaustein Is it legal (strictly speaking) to read `int_dt` after writing to `void_dt`? The standard allows conversions from `T*` to `void*` and back. But perhaps it does not mean that `T*` and corresponding `void*` have the same binary representation.

Comment: A pointer is a memory address... how could they have different representations for different types in a meaningful way?

Comment: @StefanHaustein From the standard: "A pointer to void shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as a
pointer to a character type.Similarly, pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of
compatible types shall have the same representation and alignment requirements. All
pointers to structure types shall have the same representation and alignment requirements
as each other. All pointers to union types shall have the same representation and
alignment requirements as each other. **Pointers to other types need not have the same
representation or alignment requirements.**"

Answer (score 0):

I see two mediocre solutions.  Before I go forward, I think the `switch` statement is the best option, because the program segment might not *always* be limited to just an assignment.  That said...

**Option #1:**  One Variable

Actually, this might be sensible.  Just use a `void *` variable to grab the pointer and only run the code you need, making sure to cast it in that section.

In other words, skip the `switch`/`case` concept *here* and instead move it to where the value is used, assuming you're not holding on to old values.

**Option #2:**  Exploit C's Arithmetic

```
uchr_dt = (i_type == mxUINT8_CLASS) ? (unsigned char*)mxGetData(var) : NULL;
int_dt = (i_type == mxUINT16_CLASS) ? (int*)mxGetData(var) : NULL;
uint_dt = (i_type == mxUINT32_CLASS) ? (unsigned int*)mxGetData(var) : NULL;
flt_dt = (i_type == mxSINGLE_CLASS) ? (float*)mxGetData(var) : NULL;
dbl_dt = (i_type == mxDOUBLE_CLASS) ? (double*)mxGetData(var) : NULL;
```

Kind of disgusting, but all statements in the sequence except (at most) one will assign a `NULL` and the other will make the assignment.

If you need to retain old values, you could also replace `NULL` with `(type*)xxx_dt` or something.

Like I said, though, even if one of these work, the `switch` statement is going to be the best approach in the grand scheme of things.

Comment: You can't multiply a pointer by an integer! You could turn those statements into ternaries.

Answer (score 0):

Use `char*`, have whatever sets `i_type` also set `i_size` and then use memcpy:

```
char *p = (char*) mxGetData(var);

...

double myCopy[nData];

for(i = 0; i < nData; i++)
  memcpy(myCopy + i, p + i * i_size, i_size);
```